# How to display details of user from Firebase in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

Is there only *ngFor to diplaying user details? I use this for get all users from database.but now i need to click button and show one by one's details from db.

this is my items.services.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ItemService {
 values: AngularFireObject<unknown>;
  userId: string;
}

constructor(private ebass: AngularFirestore, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth)


  getItemsList() {
    this.values = this.db.object(`signup/${this.userId}`);
    return this.values;
  }
```

And this is my profile.component.ts file. I wanna get details by user id and display it on profile.component.html file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {ItemService} from '../../services/item.service';
import {SnapshotAction} from '@angular/fire/database';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  value: SnapshotAction<Item[]>;
  constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  ngOnInit() {
       this.itemService.getItemsList().snapshotChanges().subscribe(user => {
           this.value = user;
       });
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

interface Item {
    id?: string;
    mail?: string;
    mobile?: string;
    land?: string;
    username?: string;
    firstname?: string;
  }
```

Comment: `console.log(this.value)` is the object containing user details?

Comment: it say undefined.

Comment: do this `ngOnInit() {
       this.itemService.getItemsList().snapshotChanges().subscribe(user => {
           this.value = user;     console.log(this.value);
       });
  }`

Comment: now not show any thing.

Comment: how are u displaying the data in html?

Comment: <tr class="row100 body" *ngFor="let val of values">
        <td class="cell100 column1">{{ val.id }}</td><td class="cell100 column1">{{ val.firstname }}</td>

Comment: but this is not work.

Comment: this is an object or an array of object?

Comment: array of object sir. i code this while watching video.

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ciHixbc4HE&t=125s] this video

Comment: Are you sure that itemService.getItemsList() is fetching values properly?

Comment: no this is now working and it not get any data into this.values

Answer (score 3):

Try like this. instead of initializing the value as SnapshotAction
initialize it as an empty array, or any type

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {ItemService} from '../../services/item.service';
import {SnapshotAction} from '@angular/fire/database';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
})

export class Profile-component implements OnInit {

  value: [];
  constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private afAuth: 
  AngularFireAuth) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItemsList().snapshotChanges().subscribe(user => {
       this.value = user;
   });
   console.log(this.value);
   }
}

interface Item {
    id?: string;
    mail?: string;
    mobile?: string;
    land?: string;
    username?: string;
    firstname?: string;
 }
```

> in html section try like this

```
<div class="list-group">  
    <div class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of value | async">
        <p>{{ item.payload.id | json}}</p> 
        <p>{{ item.payload.mail | json}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this would work